# F# Match is failing type comparison between 'T list' vs ''a list -> 'b list'

Tags: .net, f#

I have the following very simple function in f#:

```
let private addOnsFromDto (addOns: MyType1 []) =
        let typedList  = List.empty<MyType2>
        match addOns with
            | null -> typedList
            | _ -> List.map<MyType1 , MyType2> (fun a -> MyType2.create a.Prop1 a.Prop2)
```

The f# compiler complains with this error message:

```
All branches of a pattern match expression must return values of the same type as the first branch, which here is 'MyType2 list'. This branch returns a value of type 'MyType1 list -> MyType2 list'.
```

I understand that on the first branch I have a 'MyType2 list'. I understand that on the second branch I have a function that that maps from a list to a list 'MyType2 list' so it kind of makes sense that the compiler is complaining about inconsistent types across the two branches.

However, given that the output from the second branch is the same type as the output from the first branch I would expect the compiler to be Ok. Do I need to do something to "force" the evaluation of the List.map function so that the two types are equivalent? If so, how can I achieve this?

**Solution**

For anyone who finds it useful the solution, as explained by the helpful answers, is that I needed to pipe the original list into the map function so that both parameters were being provided.

```
let private addOnsFromDto (addOns: MyType1 []) =
        let typedList  = List.empty<MyType2>
        match addOns with
            | null -> typedList
            | _ -> addOns 
                |> Array.toList 
                |> List.map<MyType1 , MyType2> (fun a -> MyType2.create a.Prop1 a.Prop2)
```

Comment: No, the outputs are not the same: the first branch returns a list, and the second branch returns a function. Not a list, a function. Here's a hint: `List.map` takes two parameters, not one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.map` takes two arguments, but you've only supplied one. You need to add the input list as an argument:

```ml
List.map<MyType1 , MyType2> (fun a -> MyType2.create a.Prop1 a.Prop2) addOns
```

Or, more idiomatically:

```ml
addOns |> List.map (fun a -> MyType2.create a.Prop1 a.Prop2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had misunderstood that the `| _ -> ` syntax in the match statement was piping the addOns variable into the map function!

Answer (score 3):

The error message `This branch returns a value of type 'MyType1 list -> MyType2 list'.` is actually telling you that there is a missing parameter here. This is how partial application works. If you don't supply enough parameters, you'll usually get a message like this, with a type with an arrow in it. The missing parameter is the data of `addOns` of type `MyType1 list`, so addOns needs to be converted from `MyType1 array` to `MyType1 list` first.

This is what I arrived at. I have included dummy types, so that this compiles on its own. Also removed type annotations to ease reading. When you ask questions, it's nice if you can supply code that compiles.

```
type MyType1 = { Prop1: int; Prop2: float }
type MyType2 = { Prop1: int; Prop2: float }
    with
        static member create p1 p2 = { MyType2.Prop1 = p1; Prop2 = p2 }

let private addOnsFromDto (addOns: MyType1 array) =
    match addOns with
    | null -> []
    | addOns ->
        addOns
        |> Array.toList
        |> List.map (fun a -> MyType2.create a.Prop1 a.Prop2)
```

Update, Additional note: I have used a shadow declaration of `addOns` rather than underscore in the last match case. In this case perhaps it doesn't matter too much whether it's done this way or with underscore, though I prefer this way for reasons - perhaps it does matter somewhat to lessen possible errors during refactoring, and for clarity - but in other cases you don't have access to the value without doing it this way, so you must. With reference to your comment in the other answer; underscore is only a way to tell the compiler you don't need to use the value, so you don't need a name for it.

Comment: Thank you - The explanation that this type of error is typically associated with partial application is extremely helpful. I have seen this a few times before but I don't think that I understood this before. I'll know where to look next time!